# Editing Powerpoint slides in Propresenter

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to edit a powerpoint slide that has been imported into ProPresenter 6?  Currently when we find an error after importing we have to load Powerpoint, edit the slide, then re-import it into ProPresenter.  (Usually its just a basic typo or alignment issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with ProPresenter and the answer is no. ProPresenter imports PowerPoints as images. But if you want to edit them in ProPresenter just remake them in ProPresenter if you have enough time.